# typo3 site offline after extension upload

Tags: typo3

I just uploaded a new extension to a typo3 site and the site went offline. I am getting a '500 internal server error'.

What can I do to rewind the operation and/or to bring the site online again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to uninstall the extension via the extension manager module in the backend. If that is broken too then you need to do so via manually editing the configuration file. it's located in the typo3conf folder and named localconf.php for version 4.x and LocalConfiguration.php for version 6.x.

For localconf.php you need to erase the key of that extension from the two extList entries. There are two: one for the back- and one for the frontend.

For LocalConfiguration.php it's working similar, but i can't remember by heart a.t.m.

After saving this file you should remove all the typo3conf/temp* files to make sure that TYPO3 recreates them and not loads a wrong list of extensions.

Comment: I indeed have no access to the backend anymore. I will try your solution as soon as I get the login data to the hoster. Thanks Kitze