# Typo3: Tried adding an extension then my website crashed and displays a HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

I took over a website for my client and I tried adding an extension to Typo3. When I did, the whole website crashed and displays a HTTP ERROR 500. I found this thread with a similar problem, followed the instructions and erased the key that was supposed to be removed [typo3 site offline after extension upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478248/typo3-site-offline-after-extension-upload) but that didn't work.

I gained access to the cPanel since I couldn't access the backend login page. So now i'm able to access all of the root files and hopefully fix the problem. Does anyone know anything to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You should read the error log (for the PHP service or Apache, depending on how your hosting works). There you can see the actual error message which then can give you an indication what's actually wrong.

The most common reasons are:

- Extension version is not compatible with the version of TYPO3 you used (and you ignored the warning when installing).
- Extension is written in a way that it assumes you update the database schema, which may not happen automatically when you install the extension.
- Extension calls on classes that must be loaded and does not provide class loading for the installation you use (e.g. some extensions only offer composer support and won't work if you install without composer).
- Extension uses PHP modules that are not installed or is incompatible with the version of PHP that is used.

You *should* be able to recover this by using the TYPO3 install tool to manually update the database schema and perform checks that the extension works (TYPO3 8.7+ only). If that does not help we will need additional information:

- Which TYPO3 version do you use?
- Was it installed with composer?
- What is the exact error message you get in PHP error logs?
- If the extension you installed is public, a link to it would help determine why you get the error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I made a backup of the site before doing anything and then found & downloaded a backup that was done a few months ago which I didn't mind. After restoring the backup, nothing happened except now that instead of a HTTP 500 ERROR, there's another issue that's weird. What's happening is that the website now displays the number 3 on the upper left corner. (https://imgur.com/nHJE4wO)

Comment: It was installed with the Extensions Manager. I don't know what the Typo3 version is, sorry and on my cPanel I'm unable to find the Error log. (https://imgur.com/LxyyygN). At this point, I'm lost and even willing to redesign the entire website based on a cached page I've saved up or give someone access to the site and see if it can be fixed. Also when I inspect the website with Chrome, in the console it still says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). I think the Typo3 version is V6.

Comment: There's no install tool and I can't even create one. I uploaded a test.html file on the server and it works.

Comment: the `3` might be a mistyped character in any php file outside the php tags. without error logs you need to display the errors in the frontend. as you are not on the live system that should be possible (otherwise it might reveal internal information). set your installation in the install tool to development mode. the install tool always should be available (without backend) with a direct call to `.../typo3/install/`, notice the requirement for a fresh file `typoconf/ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` and a password.

Comment: Getting the PHP error logs should be a priority; the hosting provider can probably help you do that - but, even without that you can remove the new extension and restore the site, by editing files. In `typo3conf/` there should be either `PackageStates.php` or `LocalConfiguration.php` or `localconf.php` if the version is really old. For the former, change the "active" flag to `false` for the extension. For the others, look for a CSV list of extension keys that will contain the key of the new extension - then edit that CSV value to remove the new key. Then maybe clear `typo3temp` of all files.

Comment: @ClausDue I'll try doing that. In case it doesn't work, can I send you an email or if I give you access to the website could you help me? I'm willing to offer compensation if you could help me. I'll try doing what you told me and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I managed to get rid of the "3". I noticed some folders didn't have the proper permission and I changed those and now we're back to the original problem which is HTTP ERROR 500.